# yadcf select css style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatable, yadcf

I am using yadcf datatable plugin and its select css style looks like basic CSS style and not the boostrap one.

I am using datatables bootstrap features for css styling but for some reason yadcf still uses basic css style. Check the image attached.

I know you won't be easily able to figure out the problem, without a code link which I don't have.

If you have any pointers, I can get look into them.

[image]

Comment: you can setup a simple example on jsbin or jsfiddle, without that it will take me much more time to see what is the problem

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/cI8ci9?p=preview

Here you go. I know bootstrap paging is not working, but I can recreate the issue in Firefox.

In Chrome, I can see drop down, just fine. But in firefox it doesn't display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that the difference in the appearance of the `<select>` element is due to different internal browser element rendering / styling ?

For example open the following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) in Chrome and FireFox, and notice the difference... that's the same difference that you see on your plunker

In addition you haven't included the bootstrap css file on that plunker at all

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

but even with that css you need to manually add `form-control` class to the selects that are being generated by yadcf, (I can add a feature to yadcf to allow adding custom classes to select element for that)

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ub4HHnYUTQAd0u87aupj?p=preview) with bootstrap css file

---

You can edit the issue that you opened on yadcf github, asking for *the ability add custom classes to select(maybe other too) element*

Comment: I had added bootstrap css, may be it got removed during editing.  
>> You can edit the issue that you opened on yadcf github, asking for the ability add custom classes to select(maybe other too) element.  
Oh yes, that would be helpful. Let  me do it.  
>>Are you aware that the difference in the appearance of the <select> element is due to different internal browser element rendering / styling ?  
Yes, I am aware. I was hoping to have uniform view, but for a moment I missed the rendering part.  
Thanks.